# Some simple calculations of current in circuit

Tags: resistors

I know it's trivial for electronic's person. But I have difficulties with counting following task:

[image]

I'll be thankful for any assistance.

Comment: Note that writing the unit in square brackets is rather strange, it should rather be written 10V, 3Ω, etc.

Comment: As with any question on this site, we require that you show effort when asking the question.  It must stand on its own.  In fact, the homework tag has been deprecated and I've removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first circuit R2 and R3 are parallel, so you should be able to calculate their combined value (R23). Once you've done that there's only one path left: the voltage source with R1 and R23 in series, which should enable you to calculate the current and hence the voltage drop over R1 and R23. The voltage over R23 is the voltage over R2 and R3, so you can calculate the currents through each of them. And the current through R1 is just the sum of these.

The second circuit is more or less the same, but here it's R1 || R3.

*(You get 5 givens, while only 4 are required. The fifth can be derived from the others)*

**details**

\$\dfrac{1}{R23} = \dfrac{1}{R2} + \dfrac{1}{R3} = \dfrac{1}{2\Omega} + \dfrac{1}{1\Omega} = \dfrac{1.5}{\Omega} \$.
So \$R23 = \dfrac{1\Omega}{1.5} = 0.67 \Omega\$

\$I_{E} = \dfrac{E}{R1 + R23} = \dfrac{11V}{3\Omega + 0.67\Omega}=3 A\$

\$U_{R23} = I_{E} \times R23 = 3 A \times 0.67 \Omega = 2 V\$

\$I_{R2} = \dfrac{U_{R23}}{R2} = \dfrac{2 V}{2 \Omega} = 1 A\$

\$I_{R3} = I_{R23} - I_{R2} = 3 A - 1 A = 2 A\$

Comment: For first one: R23= 1/2 + 1/2 = 1, I23 = 11 / 1 = 11A, I1 = 11/3 = 3.7A, I23 + I1 = 14,7A? Is that right?

Comment: No. 1/R23 = 1/R2 + 1/R3, so R23 = 0.67 Ohm. Current from source = 11V / (R1 + R23). You forgot that it also passes through R1.

Comment: So... R23 = 1/3 + 1/2 = 1.5Ohm, then current = 11 / (3+1.5) = 2.4. | Second one: R13 = 1/0.5 + 1/2 = 2.5Ohm, current = 10 / (2.5+0.6) = 3.23. And, it's finished?

Comment: Maybe my comment wasn't clear, but my LaTeX code seems to have errors. The 1.5 = 1/R23 --> R23 = 1/1.5 = 0.67.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because of the ( just before the R2 instead of {

Comment: Anyway. The answer for 1 is: 11 / (0.67 + 3) = 2.9972752. Is it answer for question in the assignment?

Comment: Well, it's actually exactly 3 A (the 0.67 is 2/3). I(R3) is given as 2 A, and R2 is twice as big, so will have half the current, so I(R2) is 1 A. Together 3 A. So that's right.

Comment: Surely. So for the second one it is 1/R13 = 1/0.5 + 1/2 = 1. Current = 10 / (1+0.6) = 6.25. Correct?

Comment: is $\frac{1}{0.5} + \frac{1}{2}$ equal to 1??

Comment: It's 2.5. I forgotten about  1/. And it's final?

Comment: Yes. \$R13 = \frac{1}{2.5} = 0.4\$ Ohm. Total resistance = R2 + R13 = 0.6 + 0.4 = 1 Ohm. I(R2) = 10 V / 1 Ohm = 10 A. I(R1) = 8A, I(R3) = 2 A.